# To print a particular folder name in python?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, scripting, coding-style

I've made a script in python which scans all the folders and sub-folders and then prints all the folders and subfolders which begin with the word Hello.

Now I need to implement a change which is that I should be able to print any folder which has the word Hello. Like  the word could be hiHello or abcHelloxyz. So this folder must also be printed. I guess the grep command needs to be used.

```
import os

if os.path.isdir('/'):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
        for name in dirs:
             if name.startswith(("hello")):
                 print ("\n\nFile Name: "+ name)
                 name = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name)
)       
                 print ("Path     :"+name)
```

Comment: Please include the code you have so far.

Comment: import os

if os.path.isdir('/'):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
                for name in dirs:
                         if name.startswith(("hello")):
                                 print ("\n\nFile Name: "+ name)
                                 name = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name))
                                 print ("Path:"+name)

Comment: Please edit] your question and add that information to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if `'Hello'` is a substring in the `dirname` using `'Hello' in dirname`:

```
In [1]: dirname = 'hiHello'

In [3]: 'Hello' in dirname
Out[3]: True

In [4]: dirname.startswith('Hello')
Out[4]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regex:

```
dirlist = ['somedir', 'Hello', 'dirHello', 'hiHello', 'abcHello', 'randdir']
hellodir = re.findall('.*Hello.*', '\n'.join(dirlist))
print hellodir
>>['Hello', 'dirHello', 'hiHello', 'abcHello']
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed the change. 
I need to store the output in a particular folder. Should I use the shutil.move command?

import os

if os.path.isdir('/'):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
                for name in dirs:
                         if (name.find(("hello"))!=-1):
                                 print ("\n\nFile Name: "+ name)
                                 name = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name)
)
                                 print ("Path     :"+name)